# Can I use Lucene to see if a "query" would match a word?

Tags: lucene

`query_text = "Justin Beiber";` (Bieber is spelled wrong)

`word = "Bieber";`

`boolean results = does_match(query_text, word);`

**Note: Neither "Justin Beiber" nor "Bieber" is in a Lucene document**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that does that without building an index to actually run the query. However, you can create a temporary index in memory pretty easily. You will need to provide *at least* one more thing to a method like that, though, [an analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).

So you could create a doesMatch method like this:

```java
public static boolean doesMatch(String query, String doctext, Analyzer analyzer) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("text", doctext, Field.Store.NO));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("text", analyzer);
    Query parsedQuery = parser.parse(query);
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(parsedQuery, 1);

    reader.close();
    dir.close();

    return results.totalHits == 1;
}
```

Comment: is it ok to use that to find which words in a query match a hit document?